# InfiniteScroll not working for popups

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I have links on my page, which display a full screen popup with this html :

```
<div class="movie-popup-container">
     <div class="popup">
          <-- content of popup --!>
     </div>
</div>
```

My infinitescroll(the one by [Paul Irish](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll)) is as follows :

```
$('#activity').infinitescroll({
    behavior: 'local',
    binder: $('.movie-popup-container'),
    bufferPx: 100,
    loading: {
        finishedMsg: "This is the end!",
        img: "/images/loading2.gif?ver=1",
        msgText: "Loading ...",
        speed: "slow",
        selector: "#movie-activity-container #loading-status"
    },
    debug: true,
    navSelector: navSelectorNew,
    // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    nextSelector: nextSelectorNew,
    // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector: ".movie-activity-feed"
    // selector for all items you'll retrieve
});
```

I have configured the plugin to work only for the popup-scrolling and not window scrolling. It is working only for some popups, but not others, and there is no pattern. It works for the same popup that it didnt work for before, and vice versa. Contentwise all popups have the same data. The debug log is as follows :

```
//1st popup

XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetMain.jsp?productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732". jquery.min.js:2
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=0&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=2". jquery.min.js:2
["determinePath", Array[2]]
 plugins.js:51
["Binding", "bind"] plugins.js:51
["math:", 2813, 2728] plugins.js:51
["heading into ajax", "/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=2"] plugins.js:51
Using HTML via .load() method plugins.js:51
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=2". jquery.min.js:2
["contentSelector", div#movie-activity]
 plugins.js:51
["math:", 2613, 2728] plugins.js:51
["heading into ajax", "/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=3"] plugins.js:51
Using HTML via .load() method plugins.js:51
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=3". jquery.min.js:2
["contentSelector", div#movie-activity]
 plugins.js:51
["math:", 1973, 2728] plugins.js:51
["heading into ajax", "/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=4"] plugins.js:51
Using HTML via .load() method plugins.js:51
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=4". jquery.min.js:2
["contentSelector", div#movie-activity]
 plugins.js:51
["math:", 1173, 2728] plugins.js:51
["heading into ajax", "/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=5"] plugins.js:51
Using HTML via .load() method plugins.js:51
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=5". jquery.min.js:2
["Error", "end"] plugins.js:51
["Binding", "unbind"] plugins.js:51
//1st popup closed with successful scrolling

//2nd popup 
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetMain.jsp?productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732". jquery.min.js:2
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=0&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=2". jquery.min.js:2
["determinePath", Array[2]]
 plugins.js:51
["Binding", "bind"] plugins.js:51
["math:", 3113, 2728] plugins.js:51
["math:", 2813, 2728] plugins.js:51
["heading into ajax", "/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=2"] plugins.js:51
Using HTML via .load() method plugins.js:51
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=2". jquery.min.js:2
["contentSelector", div#movie-activity]
 plugins.js:51
["math:", 1984, 2728] plugins.js:51
["heading into ajax", "/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=3"] plugins.js:51
Using HTML via .load() method plugins.js:51
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=1&type=all&productId=6219a937-6d9c-4d42-81b6-85380c306732&page=3". jquery.min.js:2
["contentSelector", div#movie-activity]
 plugins.js:51
//2nd popup closed with successful scrolling

//3rd popup
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetMain.jsp?productId=cf352423-0b05-4fa2-9ca8-323842bc96c2". jquery.min.js:2
XHR finished loading: "http://example.com/GetXYZ.jsp?cache=0&type=all&productId=cf352423-0b05-4fa2-9ca8-323842bc96c2&page=2". jquery.min.js:2
["determinePath", Array[2]]
 plugins.js:51
["Binding", "bind"] plugins.js:51
["math:", 3113, 2308] plugins.js:51
["math:", 2913, 2308] plugins.js:51
["math:", 2613, 2308] plugins.js:51
["math:", 2464, 2308]
//3rd popup scrolling failed despite going till bottom.
```

For the 3rd popup in the above log, i scrolled till the bottom and it just kept showing the math-line in debug. 
Also, can you tell me what the line ["math:", 3113, 2308] represent?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided with an example that can be tested, I am going to answer this on a few assumptions:

1. You are using a plugin or a self-written script for the popups
2. The popup script will have to be initialized once for the links to open popups on a click event

If my assumptions are correct, then the issue is due to the initialization of the popups.
You should run your script again once the infinitescroll script runs. You can do this in a callback.

```
$(elem).infinitescroll(options,[callback for reinitalization of popups]);
```

Answer (score -1):

the math represents:

```
this._debug('math:', pixelsFromWindowBottomToBottom, opts.pixelsFromNavToBottom);

// if distance remaining in the scroll (including buffer) is less than the orignal nav to bottom....
return (pixelsFromWindowBottomToBottom - opts.bufferPx < opts.pixelsFromNavToBottom);
```

see https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/blob/master/jquery.infinitescroll.js

2464-40 < 2308 = false

which should call this.retrieve()

//i see that you set the bufferPx to be 100, which still should resolve to false

2464-100 < 2308 = false

would have to look into it further...